# REST resources with parameters

Tags: rest, architecture, restful-url, restful-architecture

Here is a problem. This is our simple domain: there is a number of questions and answers, a question may have several answers or doesn't have any.

Example:
*question : "Where can I get a pen?".

answer #1:"You can buy a pen in a shop."

answer #2:"You can borrow it from a friend."*

For the following situation it's possible to use the following REST resources:

```
GET /questions
GET /questions/{question_id}

GET /questions/{question_id}/answers
GET /questions/{question_id}/answers/{answer_id}
```

However some questions may have parameters like:

*"What is the distance between **{location A}** and **{location B}**?"

"What is the status of flight **{flight_number}**?"*

What is the best way to represent such questions and answers for them as REST resources?

Comment: How do these parameters manifest? E.g. let's say I'm a consumer of your REST API and I ask a question, can I ask a question between arbitrary locations, or only between locations you support.

Comment: You can ask for a distance between arbitrary locations.

Comment: But keep a note that different types of questions may contain different parameters or could be without any parameters at all. One more example is "What is the status of flight {flight_number}?". Just added this example to my original question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following links:

```
GET /questions/{question_id}/locationA:Zurich/locationB:Budapest/flightNumber:1234/answers

GET /questions/{question_id}/answers?locationA="Zurich"&locationB="Budapest"&flightNumber=1234
```

Now I am not sure you need the question id here. If there are limited number of question types, then you can add a path for each of them.

```
GET /questions/distance/from:"Zurich"/to:"Budapest"
```

You can generate this automatically from the question title:

```
GET /questions/what-is-the-distance/between:"Zurich"/and:"Budapest"
```

To be honest the URI structure does not really matter by REST services, because it is used only by machines and maybe by developers to configure the routing. REST clients should follow links instead of building URIs ([HATEOAS constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2)). So most of the APIs are not REST and most of their clients are not REST clients...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you could build something like this

```
GET /question /{questionid}?location=a&location2=b
```

And

```
GET /question /{questionid}?number=12345
```

But, it is going to have a lot of things to consider.

Who defines what the parameter names would be? Is it the caller who asks the question? I guess without more of an idea of the actors involved in interacting with these services it is hard to be more specific.

Sorry, this is not as much help as I hoped it would be when I started. :)

Comment: OP is trying to represent questions and answers in the URI format - not how to get the distance between a and b.

Comment: I do have similar thoughts. Parameter names is not a big problem right here I guess - it's possible to use param_1, param_2, ... or something like that. If not all the parameters provided then it means that questions is not found, if  there are too many parameters then I can simply ignore extra ones. What's about URI format for answers: **/questions/12?param1=value1/answers** ?

Answer (score 0):

What about considering POST as here I understand you are getting the question, but at the same time you are creating a question with filling in the variables.

Provide the variables as a list of Key Value pairs (or Dictionary) in body.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense but what do you suggest for questions without parameters? Using POST with empty body doesn't look solid.

Comment: Can you categorize your questions into two? and use whichever satisfy.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to do that. But will it look okay in terms of architecture? To ask some questions I have to use POST and sometimes I have to use GET... Then I would rather think about questions with parameters as "question templates"...